# convert prototype's findElement to jQuery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

Can someone explain the jQuery equivalent of Form.event.findElement to me?

```
$('.ad-publish-button').bind('click', function(e) { // jquery

     // section of prototype I need to convert to jquery
     if ( e.findElement('.ad').down('form').down('#location').value != '' ) {
          e.findElement('.ad').down('form').request();
     }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give it a try

```
$('.ad-publish-button').bind('click', function(e) { 
    var _form=$('form',$(e.target).closest('.ad')[0]).first();
    if ($('#location',_form).val() != '') {
        $.ajax(_form.prop('action'), {type:_form.prop('method'),data:_form.serialize()});
    }
});
```

1. `e.target` is the clicked element
2. `$(e.target).closest('.ad')[0]` is the closest ancestor with className '.ad'
    of the element from #1 . This element is used as context for the selector 'form'
    (so it will find a form inside the .ad-element)
3. `$.ajax()` will send a request(using the form- properties action+method and the serialized elements)